# altering user tag input

Tags: taxonomy-terms, input-formats

I have a content type that allows users to make their own tags, for me to be able to properly search through these tags I need them to be in a specific format.

Rather than burden users with my strict formatting guideline I would like to just alter the input to my format before creating the tag. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'format'?

Comment: the format is a single tag with all ingredients for instance, a food recipe may call for apples bacon and sugar, the format I would need is apple-bacon-sugar

Answer (score 1):

Implement  [hook_taxonomy_term_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_presave/7)  in a custom module and alter the terms according using PHP's string manipulation functions.